# Putting a custom view into another View, using XML layouts for both

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm starting to work on a game, which will have 3 views stacked on top of each other, basically a logo/ad row, a score row, and a game row. To start out with, I'm trying to have a class called Level_Score_Bar that uses an XML layout called score_bar_layout. Right now, my main XML code looks like this (Note, I've been editing this based off of the suggestions below, if I get it fixed, I'll stop editing it):

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/Title_bar">
        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"></ImageView>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout4">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <pearsonartphoto.AJEG.Level_Score_bar android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Score_Bar">
    </pearsonartphoto.AJEG.Level_Score_bar>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/Game_Row">
        <View android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/view3"></View>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Level_Score_bar.java looks like this:

```
public class Level_Score_bar extends RelativeLayout {
public Level_Score_bar(Context context, AttributeSet set, int defStyle) {
    this(context,set);
}

public Level_Score_bar(Context context, AttributeSet set) {
    super(context, set);
    this.addView(View.inflate(context,R.layout.score_bar_layout,null));
    Log.d(TAG,"Added view");
}
}
```

score_bar_layout.xml looks like this

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:text="@string/level" android:id="@+id/Level_text" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Level_text"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/Current_Level" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerVertical="false" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:id="@+id/Time_Left"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/Score_Label" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:text="@string/score"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Score_Label" android:id="@+id/Score_Value"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is, I'm not seeing the view at all. I'm sure I'm missing something small, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. I've confirmed that the addView command is being called (Via a Log.d statement), but it's just not seeming to make any difference...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong constructor if I remember correctly, try this one instead:

```
public Level_Score_bar(Context context, AttributeSet set, int defStyle) {
    super(context, set, defStyle);
    // ... 
}
```

[Edit]
Forgot to mention that since you're creating the view from XML, Android will call this constructor and it also enables you to use custom attributes if you so wish.

Comment: Turns out that it appears that the right answer is the 2 level deep one. Also, this still doesn't fix the blankness that I'm seeing, but I'll give you a +1.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of what your trying to do, please add some details : 
name of xml files
your intents, what you want to do exactly with both.

But here a re some general advices :

Override other constructors as well in your custom view classes.
One argument parameters are meant to load class from code, with a second, attributeset argument, it will be used for xml constructs.

When you refer to a custom component (child) in xml (parent), use fully qualified class name of your child class. (that will load its child layout). fully qualified is package name + class name

Regards, Stéphane

Comment: How do I tell the child class what it's layout is supposed to be?

Comment: Never mind... But, I'll give you a plus one, as I used part of this advice.

Comment: Could you explain more your solution and problem (for others) ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to call ?

```
this.addView(View.inflate(getContext(),R.layout.score_bar_layout,null));
```

Comment: also did you try to replace getContext() with the context that you receive from the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple, I feel like an idiot...

The problem was, the base layout was oriented horizontal. Simply adding a  android:orientation="vertical" was enough to make it work right. Sigh. So, what was happening was the bar was being displayed, but below the screen (Actually, to the right of it), and so it was never visible. Changing the orientation to it's intended method fixed that, so the bar could be seen, and wasn't off screen.